# Drupal large images upload

Tags: image, file-upload, drupal-7

I need to upload real large images like 10mb. When i'm trying to upload it. websrever crushes. not enought memory. I can't add it. Is there any module for resizing image on uploading?

Comment: I would suggest resize the images before uploading them. 10MB is too much for an image and Drupal will have to upload it anyway in order to do any manipulations (resize etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one,I hope it helps you to solve your problem  https://drupal.org/project/image_resize_filter

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to upload large images and don't want to resize them. For that, [you need to increase you php memory limit](https://www.drupal.org/node/207036) and [change your max file upload size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size).